# Select --Please Select-- as default of a dropdown inside a form angular 4.0 html

Tags: angular, typescript, dropdown

I have several dropdowns inside a form, however I am not able to make --Please Select-- as default selections of those dropdowns.

I am getting completely plain and blank dropdown. When clicked we can see items have been bound inside it.

HTML

```
<form novalidate (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(projectinformationFrm)" [formGroup]="projectinformationFrm">
    <select [(ngModel)]="selectedOrganization" placeholder="Organization" formControlName="OrganizationId" (change)="onSelectOrgEdit($event.target.value)" class="form-control">

        <option *ngFor="let org of OrganizationList" [ngValue]="org .OrganizationId" [selected]="org.OrganizationId==selectedOrganization">
        {{ org .OrganizationName }}
        </option>
    </select>

    <div>
        <a class="btn btn-default" (click)="modal.dismiss()"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>Cancel</a>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-save"></span>Save</button>
    </div>

</form>
```

Component.ts

```
public selectedOrganization: number=0;


LoadListforProjectManager(): void {
    try {

        this._service.get(URL)
            .subscribe(data => { this.OrganizationList = data; },
                error => this.msg = <any>error);
    }
    catch (e) {
        this._errorLogService.LogError(e);
    }
}
```

I am also getting `0,"--Please Select--"` as first item of the list from stored procedure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of getting the first item in the list as *Please Select*, create it in the Component Template. Also don't use `[(ngModel)]` along with the ReactiveForms Approach. Something like this:

```
<form novalidate (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(projectinformationFrm)" [formGroup]="projectinformationFrm">
    <select placeholder="Organization" formControlName="OrganizationId" (change)="onSelectOrgEdit($event.target.value)" class="form-control">

    <option value="null" disabled>Please select</option>

    <option *ngFor="let org of OrganizationList" [ngValue]="org .OrganizationId" [selected]="org.OrganizationId==selectedOrganization">
      {{ org .OrganizationName }}
    </option>
  </select>

  <div>
    <a class="btn btn-default" (click)="modal.dismiss()"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span>Cancel</a>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-save"></span>Save</button>
  </div>

</form>
```

> Here's a [**Working Sample StackBlitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/select-options-with-default?file=src/app/data.service.ts) for your ref.

Comment: Let me verify it